# How do I convert this matlab code to convert DNA data to binary into R?

Tags: r, matlab, dna-sequence

I'm trying to convert my DNA data to binary.

I found this code in matlab:

```
s = 'TGACTCAGTCGTTCAATCTATGCC'; % Input DNA string
[~,x] = ismember(s,'ATGC'); % Convert the ATGC into indexes
c = {'00','01','10','11'}; % Numeric strings to convert the indexes into
result = cell2mat(c(x)); % Convert the indexes into the numeric strings
```

And I did this in R

```
# Input DNA string
s <- ("TGACTCAGTCGTTCAATCTATGCC")
# Input DNA string
matrix(,x) <- is.element(s, "ATGC")
# Numeric strings to convert the indexes into
c <- c("00",'01','10','11')
#Convert the indexes into the numeric strings
cell2mat<-function(m)
  do.call(rbind, apply(m, 1, function(x) do.call(cbind,x)))
result = cell2mat(c(x))
```

But I don't know how to fix the error in the "input DNA string" part, does someone know why am I facing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `str_replace_all` function in the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
s <- "TGACTCAGTCGTTCAATCTATGCC"
str_replace_all(s, c("A" = "00", "T" = "01", "G" = "10", "C" = "11"))

[1] "011000110111001001111001011100000111010001101111"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete stranger to matlab so I'm not sure if this is close to your desired output but maybe it's on the right track:

```
# Toy DNA string
s <- ("TGACTCAGTCGTTCAATCTATGCC")

# Acid order
acid_lib <- "ATGC"

# Binary value order
bin_lib <- c("00", "01", "10", "11")

# Iterate over DNA strings and pull each letter's position in
# the matching ordered binary values
sapply(unlist(strsplit(s, "")), function(char) {
  bin_lib[unlist(gregexpr(char, acid_lib))]
})
```

Output:

```
   T    G    A    C    T    C    A    G    T    C    G    T    T    C    A    A    T    C    T    A    T    G    C    C 
"01" "10" "00" "11" "01" "11" "00" "10" "01" "11" "10" "01" "01" "11" "00" "00" "01" "11" "01" "00" "01" "10" "11" "11"
```